Where is the set of numbers: $\{3,12, 013,7013, 57013,\dotsc\}$ in the following example comes from?
Background
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Example
Consider the gollowing family of groups and homomorphis:
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\phi_4}G_3\xrightarrow{\phi_3}G_2\xrightarrow{\phi_2}G_1\xrightarrow{\phi_1}G_0. \tag{1}$$
Then, the inverse limit of this family is
$$\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i=\left\{(g_0,g_1,\cdots)\in \prod_{i=0}^{\infty}G_i\,\middle|\, \phi_{i}(g_i)=g_{i-1} \right\}.$$
An important application is the following inverse system:
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\phi_4}\mathbb{Z}/m^3\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\phi_3}\mathbb{Z}/m^2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\phi_2}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}. \tag{2}$$
Taking $m=10$, the elements of the inverse limit will be sequences $(n_1,n_2,\cdots)$, where each $n_i$ is an $i$ digit decimal whose last $i-1$ digits give $n_{i-1}$, as for example $\{3,12, 013,7013, 57013\ldots\}$.  This can be viewed as an infinite decimal going to the left:
$$\ldots57013.$$
Questions:
For the example above, I am having a hard time figuring out where the set of numbers: $\{3,12, 013,7013, 57013, \dotsc \}$ comes from?  Can someone please shed some light on the matter.

I think "12" is a typo and should be 13. My guess is it's just an arbitrary example, I don't see any significance to the particular numbers.

@DanielHast can you explain to me how set of number works. I am having a hard time understanding the example. I don't understand when it says:  "the elements of the inverse limit will be sequences $(n_1,n_2,\cdots)$, where each $n_i$ is an $i$ digit decimal whose last $i-1$ digits give $n_{i-1}$".

The textbook precedes this sequence with the words "for example", so, the numbers don't have any specific significance beyond that the author chose them as an example. The sentence up to that point describes what they're an example of; to be consistent with that, the 12 should really be a 13, as Daniel Hast mentioned. Also note that the text says this is a sequence, not a set (despite using the notation for a set).

@Kaya3 ah ok ok.  I thought I was suppose to figure out how the sequence is constructed from the quoted portion where i was having trouble understanding.

@Kaya3 ah ok ok.  I thought I was suppose to figure out how the sequence is constructed from the quoted portion where i was having trouble understanding.

This is just a random example of the type of sequences which are elements of the inverse limit.
As stated,  you can think of them as infinite decimals going to the left.
Here's a few more: $$(4,42,342,7342,97342,...)\\(1,51,251,2251,42251,...)\\(8,18,918,3918,43918,143918,...).$$

thank you for the examples.
